# Data Grid Design by Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm working on Grid and designing with bootstrap 3.

[image]

I'm using html5,css and bootstrap with React.js.

I have a data grid and  (My Grid is Fixed Data Table)

- filter input
- pagination tool
- and three small button which changes the same state in my grid(doesn't matter what they are doing but they must be seen every time).

My grid's width sometimes can be very small and some times can be very big.

- I want filter input to be in position top left of the grid
- 3 buttons to be in position top right of the grid
- pagination tool to be always center bottom of the grid

The problem is that the grid width can change every time.I want my filter output, paging tool and 3 buttons to take position always by grid's width.

My code looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div className="col-xs-2">
   <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder='Filter' />
  </div>

 <div className="pull-center">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-default" >o</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-warning">o</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-danger">o</button>
 </div> 
 <div className="col-xs-12">
       <Table>  
       </Table>          
      <PagerDemo/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't handle it now.What do you suggest about it?Can I use panel design or anything else about it?

Answer (score 0):

To make the filter and buttons the same width as the table, you can place them into a row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the pagination, you have to prepare a few classes based on the number of buttons in a row. There has to be a reasonable maximum number of horizontal buttons.

```
.pagination { display: block; }
.pagination .page-link { text-align: center; }
.pagination-1 { width: 100%; }      /* 100 / 1 */
.pagination-2 { width: 50%; }       /* 100 / 2 */
.pagination-3 { width: 33.33%; }    /* 100 / 3 */
/* ... */
.pagination-7 { width: 14.28%; }    /* 100 / 7 */
```

Now you can simply add `pagination pagination-3` to a pagination control with 3 buttons, `pagination pagination-4` for four buttons, etc.
You can also use javascript to dynamically set the width of each `.page-link`.

Comment: I tried but when table width is small it does'nt look like what I want.Filter and buttons width looks bigger than table width.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?